# How do you transfer an NFT between wallets using Solnet?

Tags: nft, wallet, transfer

While searching for this, I keep ending up back at this code sample. Is it really this complicated to transfer an NFT?
https://github.com/bmresearch/Solnet/blob/master/src/Solnet.Examples/TokenSwapExample.cs

Answer (score 2):

This example is definitely overwrought, since it's actually calling into the `spl-token-swap` program, and not just transferring a token. If you want to just do a transfer, you can do:

```
            var amount = 1;
            var sourceAccount = new PublicKey("PUT_BASE_58_HERE");
            var destinationAccount = new PublicKey("PUT_BASE_58_HERE");
            var ownerAccount = // your secret key //;
            byte[] transferTx = new TransactionBuilder().
                SetRecentBlockHash(blockHash.Result.Value.Blockhash).
                SetFeePayer(ownerAccount).
                AddInstruction(TokenProgram.Transfer(
                    sourceAccount,
                    destinationAccount,
                    amount,
                    ownerAccount)).
                Build(new List<Account> { ownerAccount });
```

I lifted this code from the normal `spl-token` example at https://github.com/bmresearch/Solnet/blob/187095995a8e2b75cace5a6230816a915c3d64f4/src/Solnet.Examples/AssociatedTokenAccountsExample.cs#L105C14-L105C14

Comment: Where are you specifying the NFT to be transferred?

Comment: The source and destination token accounts are for the NFT mint, so you would probably derive these addresses based on the NFT mint and the source / destination wallets, using the "associated token account" program. Feel free to read up on SPL token at https://spl.solana.com/token and associated-token-account at https://spl.solana.com/associated-token-account